# Java page re-direct

Tags: java, struts

What I want to do is go to a disclaimer page when they first initially hit this method, and then any time after that go to a different page.  My current method just takes to me the disclaimer page.   Let me know if furthur explanation is needed...thanks!!!

```
public int show(Action action)
throws Exception
{

    HttpServletRequest request = action.getRequest();

action.setJspURI("htemp.jsp");
return FORWARD;
}
```

Basically I need to add an If to go to a page the first time it hits this method I guess like so:

```
public int show(Action action)
throws Exception
{

    HttpServletRequest request = action.getRequest();
--->> If (FIRST TIME HITTING THE METHOD)  
          {
           go here!!!        
          }  
 action.setJspURI("htemp.jsp");
return FORWARD;
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of "first time hitting the method?" First time for each user?

Comment: Yeah first time the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the person hits the page for the first time, throw a flag on the session layer. Then anytime a person comes to the page you can check to see if it exists or not, and redirect them accordingly. Only problem with that is that they have to agree to it every time they visit unless you implement a login system.

P.S. you should be able to get the Session off of the request object you get in that first line. Then just use setAttribute on that session object.

Comment: Ah, then you can just throw a token of some sort on the session instead of the flag, so if they have logged in they don't have to see the guidelines, since I'm guessing they would have seen them the first time they signed up/signed in.

Comment: well the sign in is different, from seeing this page.  They sign in  Then if they click a button they go to this method and see the guidelines.  If they come back any other times They should go to another page.

Comment: yeah, then I would say go with the flag option then, maybe even put the flag on the login token, or just leave it seperate. But also, like I said, if they come back to the page after thier session has expired, they will see the guidelines again, unless you possibly throw the flag on the login token and just check the flag from there.

Answer (score 1):

Create a session so you can track whether it's a users first "hitting the method", so you can chose to redirect him to the disclaimer or anywhere else.