# java session tracking

Tags: jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java page re-direct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890487/java-page-re-direct)

I want to go to a certain page the first time it calls that page and go to another page all times after that while the session is is still active. I already have a login mechanism in place. I made another topic and was suggested to set a flag on the session layer. I'm not sure how to implement this.

Basically if when they press a button to go to a page it calls this:

```
public int show(Action action) throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest request = action.getRequest();
    action.setJspURI("objects/objects_guidlines.jsp");
    return FORWARD;
}
```

This is fine if they are coming here for the first time.  How can I implement a check to see if this the first time or not and subsequently send to another page?

Comment: You shouldn't re-ask the same question whenever the answers are not satisfying. Instead, give feedback by posting comments on the answers and/or by editing and improving the question to clarify more what you're really asking.

Comment: I did...but no-one responded back after an hour

Comment: @DocHoliday Wow, you waited a whole hour and none of the volunteers on stack overflow answered your question (which isn't true, they did)?

Comment: No I made a comment after they answered and didnt get a reply after that.  I thought maybe they thought it was answered, anyway I decided to ask again and explain a little better.  Jack Edmonds
below just showed me a good example, and thats what I needed...whats your problem?

Comment: @DocHoliday Already said what the problem is; his answer is the same as the ones from your original post. Expecting immediate turn-around on an all-volunteer site is silly. I didn't vote *down* your second posting, but I *did* vote to close it.

Comment: btw...Jack Edmonds helped me out

Comment: thats cool...but you...since I asked the question again, the reply I got made more sense to me

Comment: @DocHoliday Then please delete your original post to avoid confusing future visitors with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless protocol so if you want to maintain state between requests (such as whether the user has been here before), you'll need to use something like cookies or sessions.

If you want to use the session, you can get it from the HttpServletRequest and do the following:

```
public int show(Action action) throws Exception{
    HttpServletRequest request = action.getRequest();
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("has_visited_previously")!=true)
    {
        //User has not been here before so record that they are visiting.
        request.getSession().setAttribute("has_visited_previously", true);
        action.setJspURI("objects/objects_guidlines.jsp");
        return FORWARD;
    }
    else
    {
        //User has been here before.
        action.setJspURI("objects/user_has_visited_before.jsp");
        return FORWARD;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I see what you mean....

Comment: Thanx man...im running this now...I got a Incompatibale data types here

Comment: if (request.getSession().getAttribute("has_visited_previously")!=true)

Comment: I should be able to get around that

Answer (score -1):

You would need a static variable or a singleton class to check this.

In servlets you can declare a static variable to enforce this check, if you do not have access to that then you can use a singleton.

Answer also depends upon your architecture.

Comment: A static variable would be shared across all users, same with a singleton. The proper place for user-specific data is in the session.

Comment: yeah you are right, I missed the session information part.